# Why can't I retrieve the value of my hidden field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

From my Index_view.cshtml I have a Modal that will render the following action in my controller:

Notice the line:

```
 public ActionResult AddContact()
            {
                ViewBag.Dataset = 1;
                return PartialView();
            }
```

Here is my AddContact.cshtml

See the hidden field, first line after BeginForm

```
 <input type="hidden" id="dataset_Id" name="datasetId" value="@ViewBag.Dataset">

@model ResearchDataInventoryWeb.Models.Contact
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    
    <input type="hidden" id="dataset_Id" name="datasetId" value="@ViewBag.Dataset">
    <div class="section_header2">Contact</div>
    <div style="padding-top:5px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">UCID/Booth ID</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Booth_UCID, new { placeholder = "<Booth/UCID>", @class = "input-box" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Type*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="input-box" id="contact_type">
                        <option value="0">Contact Type</option>
                        <option value="1">Dataset Admin</option>
                        <option value="2">Dataset Provider</option>
                        <option value="3">Department</option>
                        <option value="4">External Collaborator</option>
                        <option value="5">Principal Investigator</option>
                        <option value="6">Research Center</option>
                        <option value="7">Vendor</option>
                    </select>
                    <label id="contactTypeError" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">Please select a Contact Type</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Name*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_Name, new { placeholder = "<First Name>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    <label id="firstNameError" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">First name is a required field</label>
                     
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { placeholder = "<Last Name>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    <label id="lastNameError" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">Last name is a required field</label>
                     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Email</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder = "<Email 1>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    <label id="emailError" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">Email is a required field</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email_2, new { placeholder = "<Email 2>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Phone</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone_Number, new { placeholder = "<Phone 1>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    <label id="phoneNumberError" class="text-danger" style="display:none;">Phone Number is a required field</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone_Number_2, new { placeholder = "<Phone 2>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Job Title</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title_Role, new { placeholder = "<Job Title>", @class = "input-box" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="display-label">Organization</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input-box" type="text" placeholder="<Organization>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="padding-left:10px; margin-top:10px;">
            <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="centerButton" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <div style="margin-left:30px">
            <submit id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:14px"><span class="smallText_red" style="padding:30px">SAVE</span></submit>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:30px">
            <submit class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:14px"><span class="smallText_red" style="padding:30px">REMOVE</span></submit>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Here is my javascript

Notice the line in the script

```
var datasetId = $("#dataset_Id").val();
    alert("dataset is " + datasetId)



   <script>
        $(function () {
    
            $('#contactForm1').removeData('validator');
            $('#contactForm1').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#contactForm1');
    
            function validation() {
                var contactTypeVar = $("#contact_type").val();
                var firstNameVar = $("#First_Name").val();
                var lastNameVar = $("#Last_Name").val();
                var emailVar = $("#Email").val();
                var phoneNumberVar = $("#Phone_Number").val();
    
                // Contact Type
                if (contactTypeVar == "0") {
                    $('#contactTypeError').css("display", "block")
                    return false
                } else {
                    $('#contactTypeError').css("display", "none")
                    return true
                }
    
                // First Name
                if (firstNameVar == "") {
                    $('#firstNameError').css("display", "block")
                    return false
                } else {
                    $('#firstNameError').css("display", "none")
                    return true
                }
    
                // Last Name
                if (lastNameVar == "") {
                    $('#lastNameError').css("display", "block")
                    return false
                } else {
                    $('#lastNameError').css("display", "none")
                    return true
                }
    
                // Email 
                if (emailVar == "") {
                    $('#emailError').css("display", "block")
                    return false
                } else {
                    $('#emailError').css("display", "none")
                    return true
                }
    
                // Phone Number
                if (phoneNumberVar == "") {
                    $('#phoneNumberError').css("display", "block")
                    return false
                } else {
                    $('#phoneNumberError').css("display", "none")
                    return true
                }
            }
    
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
                var formValid = validation();
                if (formValid) {
    
                    var booth_ucid = $("#Booth_UCID").val();
                    var contact_type = $("#conact_type").val();
                    var first_name = $("#First_Name").val();
                    var last_name = $("#Last_Name").val();
                    var email = $("#Email").val();
                    var email2 = $("#Email_2").val();
                    var phone = $("#Phone_Number").val();
                    var phone2 = $("#Phone_Number_2").val();
                    var title_role = $("#Title_Role").val();
                    **var datasetId = $("#dataset_Id").val();**
                

**alert("dataset is " + datasetId)**
                    var categoryId = $("#contact_type").val();
    
                    var data = new FormData;
                    data.append("datasetid", datasetId);
                    data.append("Booth_UCID", booth_ucid);
                    data.append("First_Name", first_name);
                    data.append("Last_Name", last_name);
                    data.append("Email", email);
                    data.append("Email_2", email2);
                    data.append("Phone_Number", phone);
                    data.append("Phone_Number_2", phone2);
                    data.append("Title_Role", title_role);
    
    
    
                    // var frm = $('#contactForm1').serialize()
    
    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Dataset/AddContact/",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (ajaxRespond) {
                            if (ajaxRespond.dbUpdateResult == "success") {
                                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                                reloadContactLinks()
                            }
                        }
                    })
    
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Keeps returning:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be lacking relevant tags. 2/3 of the code you show is neither Javascript nor jQuery. But even if you added those tags, I don't think your post holds enough information to answer your question.

Comment: I apologize, I just didn't think you needed the entire form or javascript. What can I show you, I have been on this error for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this issue. It turns out that the "#dataset_Id" of the hidden field on the modal, had the same "#dataset_Id" as the main screen. Once I changed the "#dataset_Id on the modal to "#contact_dataset_Id", I was able to retrieve the value of the hidden field.